# How do I make it required to enter password when changing user data?

Tags: elevated-session

Is it possible to enforce users to enter their password when changing their data?
For example when changing their phone number.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is this in the context of a front-end request or editing a user in the Control Panel? Are you comfortable with writing a plugin/PHP?

Comment: Thanks for replying.
This is a front-end request. So I should write a plug-in to do it ??

Answer (score 1):

Craft has a similar concept in the Control Panel for changing sensitive data like passwords/emails you could model called ["elevated sessions"](https://craftcms.com/news/new-security-features).

You could write a custom plugin and your form could post to an action in a controller in your plugin, which could check if the phone number for that user has changed.

If so, you'd prompt the user to enter their current password and either do something similar to Craft's [UsersController->actionStartElevatedSession](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/blob/develop/src/controllers/UsersController.php#L231-L239), if you need it to last for period of time, or just validate the password and let it go through once.